# IOS floating bubble as notification

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, notifications

Is there any way on implementing / hard coding a "Facebook chat head messenger" like feature? I'm trying to use it as my custom push notification instead of it being at the top of the phone only.

I've found some applications that enables this feature but it requires the IPhone to be jailbroken, and I'm trying to avoid that method. Any suggestions / links would be helpful.

[Here is an example image of the "Facebook chat head messenger feature"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvD7n.png)

Instead of messages / chat, notifications about the application are shown inside that bubble (new mail, news, updates, etc.).

Thank you in advance